# retrieve image in iphone library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

i use this code to get image from facebook profile and show it on UIImageView

```
 // Get the profile image
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[result objectForKey:@"pic"]]]];

        // Resize, crop the image to make sure it is square and renders
        // well on Retina display
        float ratio;
        float delta;
        float px = 100; // Double the pixels of the UIImageView (to render on Retina)
        CGPoint offset;
        CGSize size = image.size;
        if (size.width > size.height) {
            ratio = px / size.width;
            delta = (ratio*size.width - ratio*size.height);
            offset = CGPointMake(delta/2, 0);
        } else {
            ratio = px / size.height;
            delta = (ratio*size.height - ratio*size.width);
            offset = CGPointMake(0, delta/2);
        }
        CGRect clipRect = CGRectMake(-offset.x, -offset.y,
                                     (ratio * size.width) + delta,
                                     (ratio * size.height) + delta);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(px, px));
        UIRectClip(clipRect);
        [image drawInRect:clipRect];
        UIImage *imgThumb =   UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        [imgThumb retain];
        imageFb=imgThumb;
        [profilePhotoImageView setImage:imgThumb];
```

I want to make a button, when clicked allows the user to change the image by an image in the library of the iPhone (photos he took with the iphone ..) . I have no idea how I should proceed, help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to the user's photo library is most easily mediated with the use of `UIImagePickerController`. You create and configure and instance, set a delegate and display it modally. Implement `-imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` to be notified when the user selects an image. You can then persist this image in the user's documents directory.

[UIImagePickerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

Comment: For more control, there's the Assets Library Framework. It's "more modern" in a lot of ways and provides access to things that you can't get with `UIImagePickerController` but it doesn't provide a `UIViewController`-level API so it's a lot more work to implement.

Comment: I'm a beginner I will just use UIImagePickerController xd